# What is a a good project and to-do manager for GTK Linux?

Tags: linux, gnome, gtk, to-do

Can someone tell me the name of a good task managing program?

I tried Tasque, "tasks", "planner", all of these are not sufficient. I need to at least be able to have recurring tasks, which none of these provide. I'd like to have a program that can remind me with desktop notifications. Are there any such programs? I'm looking for:

- Simple interface.
- Be able to make recurring tasks.
- Be able to remind me (if possible.)
- Work with GTK/X11 systems.
- Code is OSS.

Answer (score 2):

Recurring tasks are currently discussed in Getting Things GNOME developement.

Just install "gtg" on your distribution to try it ( http://gtg.fritalk.com/ ).

Answer (score 1):

Check out [TaskJuggler](http://www.taskjuggler.org/).  I used it for my project management class in grad school and it worked just fine on Ubuntu.